# Moment - add 7 days to timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment to add 7 days to a date of format `2016-11-05T18:06:17.762Z`, but it's not adding days.

When I simply get today's date with a moment object, I'm able to add days. But if I convert `2016-11-05T18:06:17.762Z` to a moment object and try to add days, it doesn't add.

`var m = moment();`

[image]

`var j = moment('2016-11-05T18:06:17.762Z');`

[image]

```
m.add(7, 'days'); // Adds 7 Days
j.add(7, 'days'); // Doesn't Add Anything
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you do an assignment: `var myTimeWithAddedDays = mytime.add(7, 'days');`  ?

Comment: @DavidTansey no

Comment: Is it a browser issue? http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.format()` you can realize that the value has changed.

```js
var m = moment();
var j = moment('2016-11-05T18:06:17.762Z');
m.add(7, 'days'); // Adds 7 Days
j.add(7, 'days'); // Doesn't Add Anything
console.log(m.format());
console.log(j.format());
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

follow the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71v1hz6j/)

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust the internals of the object. Use the external methods provided and you'll see it works.

There is a reson variables like `_i` are not exposed explicitly. Sadly JS is not good at field classificaions, so it is not that easy to hide them.

```
var j = moment('2016-11-05T18:06:17.762Z');
j.add('7','days').calendar()
//"11/12/2016"

j.add('7','days').format("YYYY-MM-DDThh-mm-ss.sssZ")
//"2016-11-12T06-06-17.1717+00:00"
```